# access application name inside custom script

Tags: nsis, electron-builder

I am working on an installer for the application written using `electron` and `electron-builder`. I was able to manage most of the issues but one. During uninstall process i have to remove registry key previously set outside of `nsis` installer. I already found a way to do that:

```
DeleteRegValue HKCU "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" "APP_NAME_GOES_HERE"
```

The problem i am having is, i would like to avoid hard coding the name of app and get it instead from some variable already defined by electron or electron builder.

This is how installer looks:

[image: exmaple]

As you can see there is application name in a title of window `KIOSKMEGA-JS` and its also set at the bottom of page along with the version and its also visible in a path string. I did not define the name anywhere aside from `package.json` file. Which means that electron is somehow passing this name to `nsis`.

Does anyone know how i can access this value in my `installer.nsh` custom script? I tried things like `$APPNAME` or `$NAME`, without luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(^Name)` to access the standard language string set by the [`Name` attribute](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/Chapter4.html#aname) in a script.

It looks like electron-builder has a define named `${PRODUCT_NAME}`.